# How do I verify tax paid or not for me in startup IT company?

Tags: income-tax, india

I am working on startup IT company in India. The company takes tax every year (1500 Rs) and gives sudexo cards for 1000 rs every month to me. My question is how to find out if they really paid tax for me. How do I get form-16 from the company?

Comment: Look at your Form 26AS, in Income tax website by accessing your account. That has all the information of tax credited under your PAN number

Comment: @Ironluca please tell me the website name.

Comment: The website is https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ you will have to register though, one you have registered, you will be able to see your Form 26 AS

Comment: @Ironluca  can I get form 16 without help of company?

Comment: @Ironluca  how to find my company registered or not?

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal, the comment chain is becoming too long, refer my consolidated answer below.

Comment: Hi @KumaresanPerumal, it looks like you might have created two accounts. [Please follow these steps in the help center to merge them.](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 2):

> I am working on startup IT company in India. The company takes tax every year (1500 Rs) and gives sudexo cards for 1000 rs every month to me. My question is how to find out if they really paid tax for me. How do I get form-16 from the company?

You can get the information in Income Tax depatment website in form of Form26AS, the URL of the website is incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in You have to register to see all your current and previous tax credited under your PAN (Permanent Account Number) number.

> Ironluca can I get form 16 without help of company

No, as far as my knowledge goes, you cannot get the Form16/Form16 A/B from the site, your deductor of the income tax will have to give it. However, since all the details of your tax deduction and credit is available in Form26AS, you could get it from there.

> how to find my company registered or not?

Though, this question is not related to your earlier question; you can search for a company on Registrar of Companies website, the url is http://www.mca.gov.in/mcafoportal/viewCompanyMasterData.do you have to know the CIN of the company or other identification numbers.

Hope this helps

Comment: You are welcome, you could also accept the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: I put upvote a few minutes ago.